# Prevent user from doing a commit before pulling latest changes

Tags: git

Lets say I have the following local repository with a commit tree like this when I created a feature branch `f` from develop:

```
master --> a
            \
             \
      develop c 
               \
                \
         feature f
```

Now after sometime new features has been merged to develop `c` and my commit tree looks like this:

```
 master --> a
             \
              \
       develop c --> d --> e
                \
                 \
          feature f
```

Now I want to ensure that I do not commit before pulling the latest changes from develop.

```
master --> a
            \
             \
      develop c --> d --> e
                           \ 
                            \ 
                     feature f
```

From what I have tried, one way is to push the changes to `f`  and then try to merge `f` to develop `e` (now have new changes). Doing this obviously throw error messages from git saying develop is ahead of `f`.I am very confident that this can be done with a `post-hook`. But, can I do it with a git `pre-hook` ?

If so, how to do it and if not please suggest some other way of doing it. If possible please explain what the commands are doing?( I am just a beginner in git )

The requirement is to display some custom message in case user tries to do this.

Thanks in advance!!

**Update:**
I am working on a solution which looks like this (later this script will be called in pre-commit hook)

**tomato.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
WORKING_GIT_DIR=$1
cd $WORKING_GIT_DIR
# switch to BRANCH_TO_MERGE
BRANCH_TO_MERGE=$2
git checkout $BRANCH_TO_MERGE

PARENT_BRANCH=$(git show-branch | grep '*' | grep -v "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' | sed 's/[\^~].*//')
echo $PARENT_BRANCH
# in memory merging of feature branch and parent and look for possible conflicts
git merge-tree `git merge-base FETCH_HEAD $PARENT_BRANCH` FETCH_HEAD $PARENT_BRANCH
```

**How to run**

```
sh +x tomato.sh (PATH TO WORKING_GIT_DIR) (BRANCH_TO_MERGE)
```

**How the script works**

It tries to find the parent branch (look [here][2] for detail). 
Then do a three way merge using :

```
git merge-tree <base> <branch1> <branch2>
```

**base** -> find the best-common-ancestor between current FETCH_HEAD & parent/nearest parent branch of current parent branch
**branch1** -> current FETCH_HEAD 
**branch2** -> parent/nearest parent branch of current parent branch

This will give an in memory merge of the remote and local branch without actually changing the indexes.

Please comment if someone improves this script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On branch `develop` do `git merge feature`, solve merge conflicts, then commit.

Comment: You want to prevent users from creating *local* commits?  Just let them commit, and do merges/rebases when it's convenient.

Comment: @Oliver I think this is a good question. If it was answered, the pre-commit hook prevents from developing (= commiting)  without a notice that your basis already changed. It could just throw some warning like "reference already changed. Do a merge first? [y/n]". On the other hand you have to supply additional information what your reference is.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth no I want them to do commits locally just not on remote, I want to get some warning/ message thrown which helps them before committing to remote.

Comment: @Christoph Yes this is exactly what I have in my mind. I just don't know how to go about it. Currently what I am thinking is to get the information about the status of develop branch and check if it has been update since I created my branch. Am I thinking correctly ?

Comment: I think this would only suit a very particular workflow.  Many times I push a branch and don't yet want to merge.  Sometimes, I may **never** may want to merge (maybe that branch represents a bug repro, for example).

Comment: @Kelvin I understand that this can be done like this, but it's the exact thing that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth In my case I want to push my changes in most of the cases, eventually I am not stoping from people from making commit, I think using `pre-hook` I can pass a parameter to toggle that case. If let's say I pass `false` as my parameter which control the commit then we can do it. But atleast we can notify user that this might create a problem.

Comment: @Christoph What you suggested in the edit, I am working on it. And I don't care about scripting lang as such. ( but I am comfortable in shell & python)

Comment: I believe you would want to clarify the question to 'Warn user from doing a push before pulling latest changes from parent branch'. Isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: @MuchMore I don't just want to warn, but also want to give the option to go with the commit if he prefers (if that is possible). Are you suggesting to change the question ?

Comment: @Christoph I suppose this something like this you asked me to do in the edit suggestion. And as you suggested I tried the script I added in update is comparing the latest fetch from remote and our local and performing a 3 way merge with best common ancestor of the three. Look if you can make some improvements in this. Thanks!

Comment: @lordzuko try to save the script in `.git/hooks/` as `pre-commit` (without ending!) and make it executable if you are on a linux/mac system. The script should then run, when you commit. If it works you should post it as answer.

Comment: @Christoph have you tried running this script ? I am currently testing the script and it seems to give some segmentation fault for some cases, I can't say why. If you face such issue can you please tell me why this is happening ? Also the script does everything in memory so you can run it with some of your local git directory without messing anything up (Heads up :D)

Comment: @lordzuko could you update your question describing the present status and problem? I am not familar with bash scripts and would like to have the least effort. Furthermore, others could jump on again if you say how to integrate and use the script. (I think you can really delete all history in your question. Make it as short and precise as possible)

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to ensure that I do not commit before pulling the latest changes from develop.

This isn't possible as commits in git are local

I think what you need is a team understanding that all work is rebased on develop before pushing. To enforce this would be a code review.

There *may* be a technological way to enforce this in CI.

Comment: can you tell me more about the approach that can be taken in CI ?

Comment: A quick google shows that teamcity can access the git log as a build step, although I think your problem is teamwork rather than technical

Comment: @m.edmondson: I agree that git commits are local. But you should be able to use a script as pre-commit hook where you do the rest and access git commands where necessary. What I understand, hooks can be in any language. See e.g. [here](https://rmflight.github.io/posts/2014/02/incrementalVersionCommitHooks.html) for an R-example.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, plain git does not have any particular support for things like this, which is why concepts like [pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pull-request/info) have been added to git overlay solutions like github and bitbucket, and tools like [gerrit](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.12.3/intro-quick.html) facilitate organizational policies for review, access, etc.

Since the question is tagged github, I assume you are using that, and then I would say that you should just ignore the up to date status of local feature branches and let the developers push whatever they branched from and create a pull request from that.

If the feature branch is behind, then the pull request will show and can not be merged if there is a conflict<sup>1</sup>. Which then leaves the ball by the feature branch developer and makes it his/her responsibility to update the feature branch in order to get it merged into develop.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is of course only determined from automatic line by line merge analysis which might not detect conceptual conflicts. It is possible to define additional [requirements](https://help.github.com/articles/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/) which I assume is possible to use to reject merging of any non-up-to-date pull request if that is what you want.
Update: There just came a question [Check if a PR is up to date with the target branch](http://stackoverflow..com/q/39395684/23118).

Comment: I am trying git's three way merge using `git merge-tree` which does this in-memory without actually touching the indexes. Any suggestions ?

Comment: This tool I am trying to build is going two these two cases that you mentioned, and the `Check if a PR is up to date with the target branch` is a case which will trigger the tool, which will again call a gui tool, that I built to show the conflicts by line by line merge analysis( currently, I am not concerned with conceptual conflicts) so that user can directly go to that particular line in the file where the conflict might happen. Your insights were helpful.