# Segmentation fault in git merge-tree

Tags: git, merge

Following is a script which I wrote to solve the problem from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286349/prevent-user-from-doing-a-commit-before-pulling-latest-changes) post.
 While this script is working fine but sometimes I get into segmentation fault, look for the **OUTPUT** below.
Is this a known issue with git merge-tree ?

Can you please explain why this is happening with **git merge-tree** if possible with visualization.

Thanks in advance !!

**How to run**

```
sh +x tomato.sh (PATH TO WORKING_GIT_DIR) (BRANCH_TO_MERGE)
```

**How the script works**

It tries to find the parent branch (look [here](https://gist.github.com/joechrysler/6073741) for detail). 
Then do a three way merge using :

```
git merge-tree <base> <branch1> <branch2>
```

**base** -> find the best-common-ancestor between current FETCH_HEAD & parent/nearest parent branch of current parent branch
**branch1** -> current FETCH_HEAD 
**branch2** -> parent/nearest parent branch of current parent branch

This will give an in memory merge of the remote and local branch without actually changing the indexes.

**tomato.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
WORKING_GIT_DIR=$1
cd $WORKING_GIT_DIR
# switch to BRANCH_TO_MERGE
BRANCH_TO_MERGE=$2
git checkout $BRANCH_TO_MERGE

PARENT_BRANCH=$(git show-branch | grep '*' | grep -v "$(git rev-parse --   abbrev-ref HEAD)" | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' | sed 's/[\^~].*//')
echo $PARENT_BRANCH
# in memory merging of feature branch and parent and look for possible conflicts
git merge-tree `git merge-base FETCH_HEAD $PARENT_BRANCH` FETCH_HEAD $PARENT_BRANCH
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Switched to branch 'test2'
develop
added in local
  our    100644 fb41c877c2a1dff24132b2dab2bb37e0dfcab0ed 1
tomato.sh: line 11: 29464 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) git merge-tree `git merge-base FETCH_HEAD $PARENT_BRANCH` FETCH_HEAD $PARENT_BRANCH
```